# How to delete object from combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with objects of `Foo` type, here is the `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

The `Foo.name` is the displayed text in the combobox and `Foo.path` is the value of the selected option.

I want to delete an option from the combobox after some operation I made.

I've tried these ways:

- 1

  ```
  comboBox2.Items.Remove(@comboBox2.Text);
  ```
- 2

  ```
  comboBox2.Items.Remove(@comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
  ```
- 3

  ```
  Foo ToDelete = new Foo();
  ToDelete.name = @comboBox2.Text;
  ToDelete.path = @comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
  comboBox2.Items.Remove(ToDelete);
  ```

Nothing works for me. : / How to do this?

**UPDATE**

This is how I'm initializing my combobox:

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sites.paths[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);

        List<Foo> combo2data = new List<Foo>();

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            Foo fileInsert = new Foo();
            fileInsert.path = s;
            fileInsert.name = Path.GetFileName(s);
            combo2data.Add(fileInsert);
        }

        comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: You are putting in the objects right? So why are you trying to delete the .Text and .ToString()? Try to find the right object with Items.Find (of FindExact) and try removing the outcome of that. Pseudo: comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.Items.Find(fooItem.Text));

Comment: Another imp thing here is how are you populating the comboBox? If you are dataBinding then try removing the item from the underlying source rather than from the combo...

Comment: @Gerald Versluis  I've tried to do this these ways: `comboBox2.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox2.Items.IndexOf(comboBox2.Text));` and `comboBox2.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox2.Items.IndexOf(comboBox2.SelectedValue));` - and every time I see an error..

Comment: `System.ArgumentException: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.` - on the line with my remove command

Comment: that was the reason of my asking "How are you populating your ComboBox". You will need to delete the item from the DataSource and rebind the ComboBox, removing from the combo directly will not work...

Comment: @Arif Eqbal I updated the first post - sorry, I didn't understand it properly. So I should remove item from combo2data list and then repeat last three lines? (combobox2.datasource, combobox2.valuemember, combobox2.displaymember)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedValue); will only remove from the combobox, not from the datasource bound to the combobox. You may remove it from the datasource and re-bind the datasource.

Comment: No need to rebind datasource, just remove from the datasource and combobox will update automatically

Comment: @Stig if the source have the proper event for it

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Framework 4.8, if ComboBox.DataSource is bound (the so-called Bound Mode), then ComboBox.Items.Remove or RemoveAt will cause System.ArgumentException. In that case, you have to rebind ComboBox.DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` property.

For example: let me have `comboBox1` added to the form. In the delete button:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combox1.Remove(takes an object)
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

So you cna do it this way `combox1.Remove(selectedItem);`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to Remove Items by Index:

```
    combo2data.RemoveAt(0); //Removing by Index from the dataSource which is a List

    //Rebind
    comboBox2.DataSource = null;
    comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;  
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";  
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Suppose you want to Remove by seraching for a member value

```
    Foo item = combo2data.Where(f => f.name.Equals("Tom")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        combo2data.Remove(item);
        comboBox2.DataSource = null;
        comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;  
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";  
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 commands will remove an item from your data source.

```
list.Remove((Foo)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

or

```
list.Remove(list.Find(P=>P.name == comboBox1.SelectedText));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the secret is to first attribute null to the datasource and after rebind to a modified collection:

```
int idToRemove = 1;
var items = (cbx.DataSource as List<MyEntity>);
items.RemoveAll(v => v.Id == idToRemove);
rebindCombobox(cbx, items, "Name", "Id");


private void rebindCombobox(ComboBox cbx, IEnumerable<Object> items, String displayMember, String valueMember)
{
    cbx.DataSource = null;
    cbx.DisplayMember = displayMember;
    cbx.ValueMember = valueMember;
    cbx.DataSource = items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps delete all items in the Combobox with
`comboBox.Items.Clear();`