# Delete ComboBox Item by Index

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm seraching for a way to delete a specific item in a ComboBox by index.
I only found a way to delete the item by value with this code:

```
cbRooms.Items.Remove((ComboBoxItem)item))
```

**Update**

I want to use a code like that

```
ComboBox.Items.Remove(ComboBox.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556216/how-to-delete-object-from-combobox

Comment: Thank you... but it's unfortunately don't fit my needs...

Comment: `comboBox.Items.RemoveAt(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove item by index, using [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.removeat?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method:

```
comboBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as :

```
cbRooms.Items.RemoveAt(0); //0 = Index
```

If you want the get the index of the selected value and remove it, you can do something like :

```
int SelectedIndex = cbRooms.SelectedIndex;
// OR LIKE : int SelectedIndex = cbRooms.FindString(textBox2.Text);
cbRooms.Items.RemoveAt(SelectedIndex); //0 = Index
```

Hope that what you are looking for and my answer helped you.